# M68K: predecrement on the same register

Tags: assembly, addressing-mode, 68000

In M68040 asm, given:

```
mov.l #0x1000, %a0
mov.l -(%a0), -(%a0)
```

What is the `%a0` value after the second `mov`? Is the register decremented twice or once?

What instead of `mov.l` we use one of the few other instructions that support pre-decrement/post-increment on both source and destination?

The MC68040 UM states that `move16 (%an)+, (%an)+` performs only a single increment, but I could not find any information regarding the general case.

I am working on an emulator and do not have an actual CPU. Also, the general consensus online seems to be that `Easy68k` is not trustworthy when dealing with this kind of corner case.

Comment: The 68060 manual explicitly mentions that `move16 (%an)+,(%an)+` only increments the register once in a foot note because programmers would expect that this is not the normal behavior. I'm not sure about the 68040, but I'm 90% sure that the original 68000 would copy the word at `0xFFC` to the address `0xFF8` and `%a0` would contain the value `0xFF8` after the operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your specific example,

```
  move.w -(an),-(an)
```

the register `an` is indeed decremented twice (so, after the instruction, it is decremented by 4 - or, in your `.l` example, by 8) on a real 68000 CPU. The instruction effectively moves memory contents downwards by a word length (verified on real hardware).

`move16` is an entirely different beast and only available on the 68040 up. I suppose the specific behavior of the `move16` instruction is caused by the 68040 caching mechanisms.